# $Y $compact space, $f:X \to Y$ closed and continuous such that $f^{-1}({y})$ is compact for every $y \in Y$. Prove that $X$ is compact

Tags: general-topology

I'm having some difficulty with the following problem:

Prove that for every compact space $Y$ and a space $X$, if there exists a continuous closed function $f: X \to Y$ such that $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is compact for every $y \in Y$, then $X$ is compact as well.

Comment: The proof is on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map e.g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A space is compact if every family of closed sets with the finite intersection property (f.i.p.) has nonempty intersection.

Now take such a family $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$. Then
$$
\mathcal{F}' := \{ f[F_1\cap\dots\cap F_n] : n\in\mathbb{N},\ F_i \in \mathcal{F} \}
$$
also has the f.i.p., hence by compactness of $Y$ there's $y\in \bigcap \mathcal{F}'$. Now take $A:=f^{-1}[\{y\}]$, which is compact by assumption.

Now consider $\mathcal{F}|A := \{F\cap A :  F \in \mathcal{F} \}$. This family of closed sets relative to $A$ also has the f.i.p. by construction of $\mathcal{F}'$, hence a nonempty intersection. But now we have
$$
\varnothing \neq \bigcap\mathcal{F}|A \subseteq \bigcap\mathcal{F}.
$$

We conclude $X$ is compact.